# reading from file in matlab and store its content in 2 variables

Tags: matlab

i have input file like image below and it contains adjacency matrix+ one number in first line. so here is the problem that i cant read file in order to set this information in 2 variable
one of them stores line 1 and variable 2 stores adjacency matrix.
so what I can do about this??

its necessary to mention that adjacency matrix is not in fixed size!
Here is a picture of my question:
thnx in advanced :)

[image]

Comment: i have 1 unrelated question! is there any implementation of independent sets using genetic algorithm in matlab? i cannot find this implementation ! but in C# and java and... thats there. so i appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: That should probably be a separate question. Do you mean a heuristic for solving the Maximum Independent Set problem? A search yields [this](http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28470-heuristic-algorithm-for-finding-maximum-independent-set). Does that help?

Comment: @pyrocrasty thats good but i need to use genetic algorithm to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can read a matrix from a file into a variable with `dlmread`

   ```
   dat = dlmread('filename.ext', ',')
   ```
2. You can use indexing to separate the parts:

   ```
   x = data(1, 1)
   table = data(2:end, :)
   ```